# How to replace constants terms from python API in clingo / gringo?

Tags: python, logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

Suppose I have a the following file `foo.lp`:

```
foo(x).
```

Now when I run `gringo -t -c x=1 foo.lp` I obviously get:

```
foo(1).
```

Now I want to know how to achieve the same behavior as the `-c` command line option from the Python API, like when I have:

```
from clingo.control import Control
ctl = Control()
ctl.load('foo.lp')


#ctl.ground() # What to do here exactly?
```

So that I can access the ground program / models of the solved program with the constant term replaced.

Comment: I think you are interested in grounding subprograms, i.e. use the program directive with arguments and ground as you like. Here are some examples: https://github.com/potassco/clingo/blob/master/examples/clingo/multishot/opt.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's possible to initialize `Control` with the command-line parameters, so this does the trick:

```
ctl = Control(["-c", "x=1"])
```